# Mobile JavaScript: "text-transform: uppercase;" isn't uppercase?

Tags: javascript, mobile, input, uppercase

I have a text input field where the input must be all uppercase, so I use:

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

on the input. I know try to validate that input with some regex:

```
function isSteamID(input) {
    return /^(STEAM_)?[0-5]:[01]:\d+$/.test(input);
}
```

The problem is, on desktop browsers it works just fine, but for example on mobile Chrome it fails to validate, because the text-transform doesn't **really** makes the input uppercase, it just looks like it is.

Am I missing something here? Should I just uppercase the input again with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that the uppercase CSS feature is not implemented on that mobile browser.

The best thing to do however would be to transform the text yourself. It will also benefit on usability.

```
document.getElementById('myInput').onchange = function() {
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Well, after some rethinking on this it's a bit more complicated... One may want to insert not only a SteamID, starting (or not) with "STEAM_", but also just a simple string which then shouldn't be uppercase. At the moment I support only SteamID and CommunityID (digits) inputs, but later it should also support URL input and plain strings (to search by "Custom URL" from a Steam Community Profile). I fetch the data from, for example, a link like this: http://steamcommunity.com/id/creeten/?xml=1 - It can be "creeten" or the CommunityID, which is only digits.

Comment: You could add detection for the type of string entered by using your regex. so if the string entered starts with (case insensitive)'STEAM_' it should be converted. But if the string is anything else then don't convert..